# Handling an external screen on the iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, retain, vga

Ok, I think its possible I've misunderstood the correct way to implement an external screen on the iPad and it is causing me a lot of headaches.
*Since this is a long post, what I'm trying to do is create and send a view to an external screen over VGA, and remove the screen once I'm done with it. I'm having retain count issues so can't get it to work.*

I have a view controller that can be called up onto the iPad at any time. When this view loads (it is a remote, similar to Keynote presentation) I check for an external screen, then create a window and add a view to the extra monitor.

in my `ipadViewController.h`  <-- the view that stays on the iPad

I have

```
@interface ipadViewController : UIViewController {

PresentationViewController *presentationView;
UIScreen *externalScreen;
UIWindow *externalWindow;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScreen *externalScreen;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *externalWindow;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PresentationViewController *presentationView;
@end
```

(There is more, but that is the external screen stuff).

in `ipadViewController.m`:

```
@synthesize externalScreen;
@synthesize externalWindow;
@synthesize presentationView;
```

So I try to do a few things when the view loads:

Get the external screen (if possible)
Create a`presentationViewController` and add it to the extra screen

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self getExternalScreen];
[self createPresentationAndSendToWindow];
}
```

to get the screen I do the following `getExternalScreen:`:

```
if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
{
    for (UIScreen *currentScreen in [UIScreen screens])
    {
        if (currentScreen != [UIScreen mainScreen])
            self.externalScreen = [currentScreen autorelease];
    }

}
```

and to send the view to it `createPresentationAndSendToWindow:`:

```
if (self.presentationPath == nil) return;
PresentationViewController *viewController = [[PresentationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CanvasPresentation" bundle:nil];


self.presentationView = viewController;
[viewController release];

if (self.externalWindow == nil)
{
    CGRect externalBounds = [self.externalScreen bounds];
    self.externalWindow = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:externalBounds] autorelease];

    [self.externalWindow addSubview:self.presentationView.view];

    self.externalWindow.screen = self.externalScreen;

    [self.externalWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

in `dealloc` I try to cleanup with:

```
[presentationView release];
[externalScreen release];
//[externalWindow release]; <- that would crash
```

---

Problem I have is that when I dismiss the `remoteViewController` (it is modal), after releasing `externalScreen` has a retain count = 1 and externalWindow has retain count = 2.

The crash caused by `externalWindow release` disappears if I don't release `presentationView` (but then I'm leaking `presentationView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for (UIScreen *currentScreen in [UIScreen screens])
{
    if (currentScreen != [UIScreen mainScreen])
        self.externalScreen = [currentScreen autorelease];
}
```

Remove the `autorelease`. You shouldn't be releasing something you didn't create or retain.

Answer (score 0):

you are autoreleasing externalView on

```
self.externalWindow = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:externalBounds] autorelease];
```

and then you assign an autorelease view to it

```
self.externalScreen = [currentScreen autorelease];
```

you cannot release an autoreleased view, or it will crash.